# View Fixed Length Binary File - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, binaryfiles, flat-file

I have a binary file of fixed length. I know it has 5 fields of type double in each record. Is there any Linux utility that is able to read this file, displaying it in text format, given a input layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The od tool provides a hex dump view for binary data.